# Typescript - prototype programming with existing class/interface like Date, Array

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add some functionalities to existing class/interface like `Date`, `Array`.

The prototype programming is working, I can add both prototype and static methods to `Date` and `Array`

But when I do prototype programming with `typescript`, I cannot `import` any other module, which is inconvenient. Either can I `export` anything (I mean some functions related to Date or Array), in the same `.ts` file. If I use `import`/`export`, there will be bunch of errors.

How can I do prototype programming while leveraging `typescript` `import`/`export` ?

e.g.

```
import {
  MyModule
} from 'mymodule';

interface DateConstructor {
  isLeap(y: number): boolean;
}

Date.isLeap = function(y: number) { call my module }

export
function myfunction() { export this data related function }
```

thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to modify the standard `Date` instead of just defining a function `isLeap`?

Comment: that's just an example, i added bunch of prototype and static functions to  Date and Array

Comment: And that's considered a bad practice, don't modify the standard objects

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend a prototype as follows:

```
interface Date {
    isEquals(d: Date): boolean;
}

Date.prototype.isEquals = function(d: Date) {
    return this.getTime() === d.getTime();
}

const d1 = new Date();

setTimeout(() => {
    const d2 = new Date();
    console.log(d1.isEquals(d2));
}, 1000);
```

This should be compatible with ES6 modules. Make sure that you are using the `--module` compilation flag in your command line or in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I have no problem with extending Date, Array

the problem is I want to use typescript import/export in the same file

if you import some module in that file or export some function/class, there will be complie errors